# Jtable in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a BoxLayout (in a panel of a BorderLayout) in which I've put  a JTable and a button vertically. I would like the table to have a fixed width and that the height should resize itself up to filling the panel. At the moment, I'm fine with the displayed width but not that it's filling up the whole panel height. For example, if there are zero data in the table, I would like only the column names to be shown. I've tried things like setViewportView() and setPreferredSize(), but can't really make it work. Any suggestions? Is it in the layout or scrollpane?

```
String[] columnNames = { "Date", "Type"
    };
Object[][] data = { 
    };
JTable myTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");

JPanel panWest = new JPanel();
panWest.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panWest, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myTable);
panWest.add(scrollPane);
panWest.add(okButton);
```

EDIT
This is what ended up working:

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension();
dimension.height =     (myTable.getRowCount()*myTable.getRowHeight())+
myTable.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize().height;
dimension.width = myTable.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth();
scrollPane.setMaximumSize(dimension);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like the table to have a fixed width and that the height
>   should resize itself up to filling the panel.

and

> I have a BoxLayout (in a panel of a BorderLayout) in which I've put a
>   JTable and a button vertically.

there are three (mentioned only simple) ways

- use built_in `LayoutManager` for `JPanel` - `FlowLayout` (`FLowLayout.CENTER`),

  1. override `FLowLayout.LEFT` or `RIGHT` in the case that you want to aling,
  2. `JComponent` laid by `FlowLayout` never will be resizable without programatically to change `XxxSize` and notified by `revalidate` & `repaint`,
  3. set proper size for JScrollPane by override `JTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(int, int));`,
  4. JScrollPane accepts this Dimension as initial size, required is usage of  `JFrame.pack(`), before `JFrame.setVisible(true)`
- `BoxLayout` accepts `min, max and preferred size`, override all these three sizes for `JScrollPane`
- (`half solution, but most comfortable`) change `LayoutManager` for `JPanel` to `BorderLayout`,

  1. put `JScrollPane` with `JTable` to `BorderLayout.EAST/WEST` area,
  2. then override `JTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(int, int));`,
  3. `JScrollPane` will occupy whole area for `BorderLayout.EAST/WEST` and will be resizeable only on `heights` coordinates

---

- use `MigLayout`, here are a few posts about `MigLayout` and `JScrollPane` (with `JTextArea`, `JTable`)

Comment: Thanks for the help! It made sence to me to use the minimum/preferred size + maximum size, but turned out I only needed to set the maximum size.